# How to get difference between two array in JavaScript based on condition using lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have two arrays like below:

```
var oldArray = [{ id: '10', name: 'ABC', type: 'type1' },
                { id: '11', name: 'XYZ', type: 'type1' }]

var newArray=[{ id: '10', name: 'ABC', type: 'type1' },
              { id: '11', name: 'XYZ', type: 'type1' }
              { id: '12', name: 'PQR', type: 'type1' },
              { id: '13', name: 'SomeNewData', type: 'type2' }]
```

I want to get that `PQR` object from the `newArray` because it is of `type1` and the only object which is difference in the `oldArray` and push that object into `oldArray`.

I tried it using the `difference` method of lodash but I couldn't get it done. Can I achieve this using `lodash`? Any solution using native JavaScript will also be useful.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What about "SomeNewData"?

Comment: Are IDs unique? And by "difference", do you mean elements in `newArray` that are not in `oldArray`? Or do you want even elements in `oldArray` that are not in `newArray`?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl `SomeNewData` I won't need this because it is of `type2`. I only need the difference between those of `type1`.

Comment: @Uby I just need that `PQR` object with less and meaningful code using `Lodash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the difference using `filter` and `some` methods and also check the type.

```js
var oldArray = [{ id: '10', name: 'ABC', type: 'type1' }, { id: '11', name: 'XYZ', type: 'type1' }]
var newArray=[{ id: '10', name: 'ABC', type: 'type1' }, { id: '11', name: 'XYZ', type: 'type1' }, { id: '12', name: 'PQR', type: 'type1' }, { id: '13', name: 'SomeNewData', type: 'type2' }]
              
var diff = newArray.filter(({ id, type }) => (
  type == 'type1' && !oldArray.some(e => e.id == id)
))

console.log(diff)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Can I get that as an object instead of inside an array?

Comment: What if you have multiple objects that pass the condition?

Comment: Btw to push each object from diff to oldArray you can use `oldArray.push(...diff)`

Answer (score 1):

You can diff the two arrays by comparing the objects by equivalency. The basic `isEq` function below was borrowed from here: ["Object Equality in JavaScript"](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/object-equality-in-javascript.html).

Once you can compare two objects, just diff them by looping over both arrays and building a difference array by checking if the current item exists in the other list.

You do this two times, once for the first list and again for the second. Except on the second time around, you check if the item is already in the diff list.

**Edit:** If you only want to look at items where `type = "type1"`, filter them out before you proceed.

```js
var oldArray = [{
  id: '10',
  name: 'ABC',
  type: 'type1'
}, {
  id: '11',
  name: 'XYZ',
  type: 'type1'
}]

var newArray = [{
  id: '10',
  name: 'ABC',
  type: 'type1'
}, {
  id: '11',
  name: 'XYZ',
  type: 'type1'
}, {
  id: '12',
  name: 'PQR',
  type: 'type1'
}, {
  id: '13',
  name: 'SomeNewData',
  type: 'type2'
}]

console.log(diff(
  oldArray.filter(item => item.type === 'type1'),
  newArray.filter(item => item.type === 'type1')
));

function diff(arrA, arrB) {
  let diff = [];
  arrA.forEach(itemA => {
    if (!arrB.some(itemB => isEq(itemA, itemB))) {
      diff.push(itemA);
    }
  })
  arrB.forEach(itemB => {
    if (!diff.some(p => isEq(itemB, p)) && !arrA.some(itemA => isEq(itemA, itemB))) {
      diff.push(itemB);
    }
  })
  return diff;
}

function isEq(a, b) {
  var aProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a);
  var bProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b);
  if (aProps.length != bProps.length) {
    return false;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < aProps.length; i++) {
    var propName = aProps[i];
    if (a[propName] !== b[propName]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

How with vanilla?

```js
var oldArray = [{
    id: '10',
    name: 'ABC',
    type: 'type1'
  },
  {
    id: '11',
    name: 'XYZ',
    type: 'type1'
  }
]

var newArray = [{
    id: '10',
    name: 'ABC',
    type: 'type1'
  },
  {
    id: '11',
    name: 'XYZ',
    type: 'type1'
  }, {
    id: '12',
    name: 'PQR',
    type: 'type1'
  },
  {
    id: '13',
    name: 'SomeNewData',
    type: 'type2'
  }
]

var existingArray = oldArray.map(arr => arr.id);

var filteredArray = newArray.filter(arr => arr.type === 'type1' && !existingArray.includes(arr.id));

var mergedArray = oldArray.concat(filteredArray);

console.log(mergedArray);
```

Comment: This is indeed useful. Thanks!